# Filling arrays with prime numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi guys my task is to fill the array with first prime numbers of an entered number N.The size of the array is given..Here is my solution.Thanks a lot guys!
Here is the output Enter a number: 77
-858993460 -858993460 2 3 -858993460 5 -858993460 7 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 11 -858993460 13 Press any key to continue

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    bool primenumber(int number) {
        int p = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            if (number%i == 0) {
                p++;
            }
        }

        if (p == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void fillArray(int array[], const int N){
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            if (primenumber(i))
                array[i] = i;
        }
    }
    void printArray(int array[], const int N){
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            cout << array[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        const int N = 14;
        int array[N];
        int number = 0;
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> number;
        fillArray(array, number);
        printArray(array, N);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Is there some specific error with this solution? Please add compiler error messages, or expected vs actual results.

Comment: What are _" prime numbers of an entered number N"_? Do you mean prime factors of `N`? Or do you  mean the first _N_ prime numbers?

Comment: there is no error with compiling but the output isnt right Enter a number: 77
-858993460 -858993460 2 3 -858993460 5 -858993460 7 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 11 -858993460 13 Press any key to continue

Comment: That is because in `fillArray` you are only assigning something to `array[i]` when `i` is a prime number.

Comment: Try using C++, since yeh tagged yer question with it

Comment: the task is : create a function which will fill your array with prime numbers of an entered number,where N is the size of the array. Btw the size of array is given to 14.

Comment: I think your edit just made things less clear. Can you please format it and elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `array[i]` to `i` if `i` is a prime number. But you do not set `array[i]` to any value if `i` is not a prime number. You probably only want to store the prime numbers in `array`, so

```
void fillArray(int array[], const int N){
    for (int i = 2, j = 0; j < N; ++i){
        if (primenumber(i))
            array[j++] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: guys mistake is in homework...I have to enter a number then I have to store all prime numbers in the array of size 14.

Comment: @printline Then don't write that as a comment on my answer, change you question to make it more clear. And BTW; my answer fixes your problem. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

1st things first...You need to initialize your array.
Use this for your prime number function

```
bool primenumber(int number) {
    for(int i(2); i <= sqrt(number); ++i) {
        if(number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Secondly, because you've fixed the size of your array to 14, anytime you look for numbers larger than 13 your array will be `0 0 2 3 0 5 0 7 0 0 0 11 0 13`.  My guess this is a homework problem and you should look into using `new` to dynamically allocate memory to grow your array.  Don't forget to `delete []` for each `new`.